# Making a responsive rectangle that is higher then width with centered content

Tags: html, css

For my website, I want to make a rectangle that is responsive and where I can adjust the height and width easily. I tried to turn the rectangle but when I do that the content also turns 90 degrees. Maybe you can help me?

Already much thanks

Code in snippet:

```css
.project-pill{
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);    
}
.project-pill::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 80%;
}
.project-pill .content{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-project">
    <div class="project-pill">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "standing up instead of laying down"? Can't you just set the height larger than width?

Comment: Btw. you can "un-rotate" the content with `.content { transform: rotate(90deg); }` (https://jsfiddle.net/oz6keojk/). But it still seems a bit weird to do that…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to make a responsive rectangle/square is using `padding-top` property.

`*If your code is responsive it can not be a fixed height*`

The rectangle width will be based on the parent width and the height is 150% the parent width.

Look at the code:

```css
.rec{
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150%;
}

.content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rec">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem rerum illo delectus laborum reiciendis atque et aperiam vitae, vel alias quia cum eaque corrupti. Ad tenetur consectetur perferendis consequatur illum?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you just want a box taller than wider, correct?

If yes, as said in the comments, there is the simple way, just setting height bigger than width:

```css
.project-pill{
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35%;
  height: 200px;
}

.project-pill .content{
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper-project{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-project">
    <div class="project-pill">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

OR, using your way and un-rotating the content: (but I really can't understand why you need to rotate it)

```css
.project-pill{
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);    
}
.project-pill::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 80%;  
}
.project-pill .content{
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);   
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-project">
    <div class="project-pill">
        <div class="content">
Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, the problem with the height in pixels is that the rectangle not responsive. Is there a way to fix that? Already much thank for your help!

Comment: Maybe you can use `vh`, that will adjust according to screen viewHeight, eg. `50vh` will use 50% of the screen height. OR you can use media queries to set heights for different screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks man I did not think of that but it worked so thank you very much!